# Let $f:c_0\to \mathbb{F} $ be given by $f(x_1, x_2, . . .) =x_1$. Determine all the Hahn-Banach extensions of $f$ to the space $c$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

This question had to parts.

$a)$ Calculate $‖f‖$.

$b)$ Determine all the Hahn-Banach extensions of $f$ to the space $c$.

My work:

$a)$ Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, then $||f(x)||=||(x_1)||\leq||x||_{\infty}$ . This means that $||f||\leq1$. Choose $x=(1,0,\ldots)$ then $||x||_{\infty}=1$ and $||f(x)||=1$. Which means that $||f||=1$

$b)$ is where I get stuck. I know that I can write $c=c_0\oplus \lambda(1,1\ldots)$. However I am unsure how to continue from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a good start.  By noting the direct sum decomposition of $ c $, you know that any extension is completely determined by $ f $ along with its value at $ \mathbf{w} = (1, 1, \ldots) $.  Call this value $ f(\mathbf{w}) = k \in \mathbb{F} $.  Then you can calculate
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{f}(\mathbf{x}) &= f(\pi_{c_0} \mathbf{x} + \pi_{c_0^\perp}\mathbf{x})\\
&= f(\pi_{c_0} \mathbf{x}) + \bar f(\pi_{c_0^\perp} \mathbf{x})\\
&= f(\mathbf{x} - (\lim{\mathbf{x}}) \mathbf{w}) +  \bar f((\lim{\mathbf{x}}) \mathbf{w})\\
&=f(\mathbf{x} - (\lim{\mathbf{x}})\mathbf{w}) + \lim \mathbf{x}\ \cdot \bar f(\mathbf{w})\\
&=f(\mathbf{x} - (\lim{\mathbf{x}})\mathbf{w}) + k \lim \mathbf{x}
\end{align}
$$
Edit: I noticed from our calculations in the comments that there is only one value of $ k $ which yields an extension $ \bar f $ of norm no larger than that of $ f $.  So this problem is more interesting than I at first realized.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried doing that and I got that $\bar{f}(x)=x_1+(k-1)\lim\, x$. However what I've been struggling to figure out is if this is good for any $k\in\mathbb{F}$ or more precisely how would I go about calculating the norm of this $\bar{f}$.

Comment: Well let's think what is the biggest we can make $ \bar f $ with an $ \mathbf{x} $ of norm 1.  Clearly we can and should take $ x_1 = 1 $.  Then the biggest we can make the second term is to take $ \lim \mathbf{x} = \mathrm{sgn}(k-1) $.  With this element, we maximize $ f(\mathbf{x}) $, giving a norm of $ 1 + |k-1| $.    This is a somewhat hand-wavy argument, so you should fill in the details with a proper chain of inequalities.

Comment: To get you started: $ |\bar f(x)| \leq |x_1| + |(k-1) \lim \mathbf{x}| \leq \ldots $.

Comment: What I was thinking of doing was something like this. We know that $|\bar{f}|\geq |f|$ as $\bar{f}$ extends $f$ therefore $|\bar{f}|\geq 1$. However for it to be an extension the norm has to equal 1. If I understand correctly. the last inequality says that $|\bar{f}|\leq |x_1|+|k-1||\lim x|\leq|x|_{\infty}+|k-1||x|_{\infty}=k|x|_{\infty}$ Which would mean that only $k=1$ works?

Comment: @Westlife yes that reasoning seems right to me.